# How to give percentage weight in constraint layout android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

How to design below screen with stretchable space for remaining space based on device height

I can easily design it using linearlayout using weigh and weight sum attribute but not sure how to do it in constraint layout

[image]

Comment: Hi Jess, have you some attempts that we can continue on?

Comment: Give me moment i will add that to question.

Comment: @zain not able to post the code getting error -  It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: what is the 20% means WRT the screen?

Comment: imagine device height is 100px then if other elements(image, 2editetxt and button) takes around 50% of screen then remaining 50% space should be distributed among the space as top and bottom 40% means 20px and middle space should be 10 px.

Comment: I found this site to be very useful, take sometime out and go through it 
https://constraintlayout.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the views that you have defined have a defined height (either `wrap_content` or a specified height) then the question is how to distribute the left-over space. If I read your question correctly, you want 40% of the left-over space to be at the top, 20% in the middle and 40% at the bottom for a total of 100% of the space and 100% of the space is the height of the *ConstraintLayout* less the combined heights of the widgets.

You can use weights in a *ConstraintLayout* chains to distribute weights, but the weights will be assigned to [Space widgets](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space) as follows. All the views must be part of a vertical chain constrained to the top and bottom of the *ConstraintLayout*.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space40.1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="40" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/space20"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/space40.1" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space20"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="20" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/space20" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view4"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/space40.2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view3" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space40.2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view4"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="40" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The layout displays as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can combine [GuideLines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html) with percentage values like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button3"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

*Here is how it looks on preview (and on the device if you try to run it):*

[image]